# Frontend interaction with smart contract method Error: non-payable method cannot override value

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity

trying to call a mint method in a smart contract deployed here: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x86C31eA7a0D8996db3cB9da52F3386DA6029a387#code

```
  function mintTo(address recipient) public payable returns (uint256) {
    uint256 tokenId = currentTokenId.current();
    require(tokenId < TOTAL_SUPPLY, "Max supply reached");
    require(!_exists(tokenId), "ERC721: token already minted");
    // require(count > 0 && count <= 10, "You can mint between 1 and 10 at once");
    require(msg.value == MINT_PRICE, "Transaction value did not equal the mint price");

    currentTokenId.increment();
    uint256 newItemId = currentTokenId.current();
    _safeMint(recipient, newItemId);
    return newItemId;
  }
```

Frontend code:

```
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum)
    const signer = provider.getSigner()
    const nftContract = new ethers.Contract(
      nftContractAddress,
      NFT.abi,
      signer
    )

    const options = { value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.00420") }

    let nftTx = await nftContract.mintTo(currentAccount, options)
```

error:

```
Error minting character Error: non-payable method cannot override value (operation="overrides.value", value={"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x0eebe0b40e8000"}, code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=contracts/5.6.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

so ... after hours of searching, I realised that I was referencing a different contract. the above code works, it was just weird that the method was non-payable even though the last deploy included a payable `mintTo` method.

:|

Answer (score 0):

The error is that the contract method is not payable，For example：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmXVc.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).